# jolt transformation for nested specific key in lowercase

Tags: json, jolt

I have a JSON input :

```json
{
  "levelOne": [
    {
      "leveltwo": {
        "levelThree": [
          {
            "type": "typeOne",
            "leveltwo": {
              "Id": "101000094794",
              "Id2": "101000013207"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "typeTwo",
            "leveltwo": {
              "Id": "101000013207",
              "Id2": "101000013207"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a jolt spec that would lowercase every key, including keys in nested objects? (in this case what is under leveltwo)

```json
{
  "levelone": [
    {
      "leveltwo": {
        "levelThree": [
          {
            "id": "101000094794",
            "id2": "101000013207",
            "type": "typeOne"
          },
          {
            "id": "101000013207",
            "id2": "101000013207",
            "type": "typeTwo"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Currently, I'm using following spec (jolt template):`

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "levelOne": {
        "*": {
          "leveltwo": {
            "id": "&3[&2].leveltwo.id",
            "levelThree": {
              "*": {
                "leveltwo": {
                  "Id": "&6[&5].leveltwo.&3[&2].id",
                  "Id2": "&6[&5].leveltwo.&3[&2].id2"
                },
                "type": "&5[&4].leveltwo.&2[&1].type"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "&1.key",
        "@": "&1.value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "levelOne": {
        "key": "=toLower"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "value": "@(1,key)"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Expected result (key should be in lower levelThree, typeOne, typeTwo):

```json
{
  "levelone": [
    {
      "leveltwo": {
        "levelthree": [
          {
            "id": "101000094794",
            "id2": "101000013207",
            "type": "typeone"
          },
          {
            "id": "101000013207",
            "id2": "101000013207",
            "type": "typetwo"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can repeatedly apply the consecutive `shift`-`modify`-`shift` trio per each object key(`levelOne` and `levelThree` in this case) which needs a case conversion such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "id": "&3[&2].&1.id",
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "*": {
                  "Id": "&6[&5].&1.&3[&2].id",
                  "Id2": "&6[&5].&1.&3[&2].id2"
                },
                "type": "&5[&4].&3.&2[&1].type"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "&1.key",
        "@": "&1.value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "key": "=toLower"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "value": "@(1,key)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "$": "&4.&3.&2.&1.key",
              "@": "&4.&3.&2.&1.value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "key": "=toLower",
              "value": {
                "*": {
                  "type": "=toLower"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "value": "&4[&3].&2.@(1,key)"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Another approach might be as follows :

```json
[
  { // combine the attributes and subattributes of the innermost array under the common objects of the newly created array, namely "values"
    // while reforming a new array namely "key"
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // the level of levelOne
        "*": { // the level of indexes of levelOne 
          "*": { // the level of leveltwo
            "*": { // the level of levelThree
              "$3|$2|$1|$": "key",
              "*": { // the level of indexes of levelThree
                "type": "value[&1].&",
                "level*": {
                  "*": "value[&2].&"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // convert all letters of the keys and values into lowercase
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "k*": "=toLower",
      "v*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "=toLower"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "key": {
        "*": { // expand the members of the array to the integer index vs. values pairs
          "@": "&2.&"
        }
      },
      "value": {
        "*": "&1[&]"
      }
    }
  },
  {// construct the result by matching "value" array with stairs-style qualified values coming from the "key" array 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "key": {
        "@1,value": "@(1,0)[@(1,1)].@(1,2).@(1,3)"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: could you please try with the help of operation only  after spec ?

Comment: Hi @PriyankaKoushal I've just added a new approach with some more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Priyanka this spec will resolve your issue. You can use =toLower case function in modify-overwrite-beta operation.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "levelOne": {
        "*": {
          "leveltwo": {
            "levelThree": {
              "*": {
                "leveltwo": {
                  "*": { 
                    //unwraps the field key and value into 2 feilds(key,Value). 
                    "$": "levelOne.[#4].leveltwo.levelThree.[#2].leveltwo.key",
                    "@": "levelOne.[#4].leveltwo.levelThree.[#2].leveltwo.value"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "levelOne": {
        "*": {
          "leveltwo": {
            "levelThree": {
              "*": {
                "leveltwo": {
                  //Key is on right side using toLower to make it lowercase.
                  "key": "=toLower"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "levelOne": {
        "*": {
          "leveltwo": {
            "levelThree": {
              "*": {
                "leveltwo": {
                   // Forming the original fields from key and value fields
                  "value": "levelOne.[#6].leveltwo.levelThree.[#2].leveltwo.@(1,key)"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can be sure about all things to be lower with this jolt spec. You can modify each `location`, `keys`, or `values` in the `modify` step.

Please run each spec to see what happened.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // levelOne
        "*": { // 0
          "*": { // leveltwo
            "*": { // levelThree
              "*": { // 0, 1
                "type": {
                  "$": "[&2].keys"
                },
                "*": {
                  "$5": "[&2].location",
                  "$4": "[&2].location",
                  "$3": "[&2].location",
                  "$2": "[&2].location",
                  "@(1,type)": "[&2].values",
                  "*": {
                    "$": "[&3].keys",
                    "@": "[&3].values"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "keys|values|location": {
          "*": "=toLower"
        },
        "locatio*": "=join('-',@(1,location))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "keys": "@(1,location).&1.&",
        "values": "@(1,location).&1.&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*-*-*-*": {
        "*": {
          "values": {
            "*": {
              "@": "&(4,1)[&(4,2)].&(4,3).&(4,4)[&3].@(3,keys[&1])"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Note:** If you want to prevent to lower your values you can change this line `keys|values|location` in the `modify`, to this `keys|location`.

Comment: could you please try with the help of operation only after spec ?

Comment: @PriyankaKoushal I couldn't understand what you meant. Do you need help understanding how each operator works?

Comment: Yes ,Actually I'm using jolt template with huge input in which i have output but for some nested key i'm not able to convert in lowercase so can we add new Operations not whole template ?

Comment: @PriyankaKoushal Can you share the real simplified input?

Comment: INPUT : {"id":"12345","date":"2023-03-15","item":[{"id":"1847546","name":"abcd"}],"levelOne":[{"id":"6789","place":"place_name","leveltwo":{"levelThree":[{"type":"typeOne","leveltwo":{"Id":"101000094794","Id2":"101000013207"}},{"type":"typeTwo","leveltwo":{"Id":"101000013207","Id2":"101000013207"}}]},"unit":{"id":"68538"},"inneritem":[{"id":"1847546601","name":"abcd"}],"pattern":[{"name":"DOMAIN1","value":"SOS"},{"name":"DOMAIN2","value":"POP"}]}]}

Comment: EXPECTED OUTPUT: {"id":"12345","date":"2023-03-15","item":[{"id":"1847546","name":"abcd"}],"levelone":[{"id":"6789","place":"place_name","DOMAIN1":"SOS","DOMAIN2":"POP","leveltwo":{"levelThree":[{"id":"101000094794","id2":"101000013207","type":"typeOne"},{"id":"101000013207","id2":"101000013207","type":"typeTwo"}]},"unit":{"id":"68538"},"inneritem":[{"id":"1847546601","name":"abcd"}]}]}

Comment: USING JOLT SPEC: [{"operation":"shift","spec":{"id":"id","date":"date","item":"item","levelOne":{"*":{"id":"&2[&1].&","place":"&2[&1].&","pattern":{"*":{"name":{"DOMAIN1":{"@2,value":"&6[&5].DOMAIN1"},"DOMAIN2":{"@2,value":"&6[&5].DOMAIN2"}}}},"leveltwo":{"id":"&3[&2].id","levelThree":{"*":{"leveltwo":{"Id":"&6[&5].leveltwo.&3[&2].id","Id2":"&6[&5].leveltwo.&3[&2].id2"},"type":"&5[&4].leveltwo.&2[&1].type"}}},"unit":{"id":"&3[&2].unit.id"},"inneritem":"&2[&1].inneritem"}}}}]

Comment: and below Operations i'm using:
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "&1.key",
        "@": "&1.value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "key": "=toLower"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "value": "@(1,key)"
      }
    }
  }